# When does java execute class-level field assignments?

Tags: java, class, field

I would consider myself somewhat beginner/intermediate in programming; Most of the time it seems I know how to code things, but I don't know exactly what java does with it. Sometimes I have a field that is assigned in a constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
     public int x;
     
     MyClass() {
       x = 5;
     }
}
```

...And as far as I know x gets set to 5 when a new object of MyClass is created. However, sometimes I assign fields outside of any constructor or function:

```
public class MyClass {
     public int x = 5;
     public static MyOtherClass y = new MyOtherClass();
 
     public MyClass() {

     }
}
```

When exactly does java run these assignments? Are they also done when an object of MyClass is created, or before then? If I reference a static variable such as "y":

```
public class MyThirdClass {
     public MyOtherClass z = MyClass.y;
}
```

Is "y" assigned when I first reference it, or does Java already have it done before then? In this case "y" can't be assigned after creating a new object of MyClass, because I haven't created any objects for it yet. So are all these field assignments outside of constructors and methods done all at once when the program is run, or instead assigned when they are first referenced/needed? Or some other time? Thank you for any info on this.

Comment: They are considered as part of *initialization block* (the one `{..}` without "name"). For instance `int val1 = 1; int val2; { val2=2; } int val3 = 3;` can be considered as `int val1; int val2; int val3; {val1=1; val2=2; val3=3}`. Initialization blocks are copied at start of each constructor (well, after its `super(..)` call, implicit or explicit). So if you have `int val = 42;` and in constructor you would write `MyClass(){val = 10;}` then it will be compiled as if it was written `MyClass(){super(); {val=42;} val=10;}`. So values from constructor will override values set directly in field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member variable initializers like this:

```
public class MyClass {
     public int x = 5;
     public int y;
     
     MyClass() {
       y = 6;
     }
}
```

are inlined into all constructors which invoke a super constructor (either implicitly or explicitly), in-between the call to the super constructor, and the rest of the constructor body:

```
public class MyClass {
     public int x;
     
     MyClass() {
       super();
       x = 5;
       y = 6;
     }
}
```

It's not just member variable initializers: member variable initializers are basically like member declarations, followed by an instance initializer:

```
public int x = 5;

// is the same as

public int x;

{
  x = 5;
}
```

All the instance initializers in the class are inlined into the super-invoking constructors, in the order in which they are declared in the class.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. What about if they are static, and the constructor is never called?